# Thermostat wiring with external transformer

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

So I am trying to wire a Honeywell lyric thermostat and I tried following videos but got a little stuck. So I have wires R, W ,Y , G coming to my original thermostat. I bought an 24V external transformer to power the thermostat. I have two wires coming from the external transformer. Where should the wires go on the new Honeywell lyric?

thanks for the help

Comment: Is there not a way to route a C wire from your existing system? Can you post photos of your thermostat wiring at both ends?

Answer (score 0):

Connect one end of the transformer to Rc on the thermostat, the existing R wire to R on the thermostat, and the other end of transformer to C on the thermostat.  Also make sure to set the switch under the R and Rc terminals to the "R/Rc" position.

Comment: I would expect a new transformer to provide an isolated 24V output, with neither output bonded to ground, i.e. both ungrounded wires.  If both the new transformer and the old one are *not* isolated, that's just asking for crazy trouble.

Comment: This will work if you are only controlling a heating system.  If you're controlling heating and cooling, you might get some strange results when the thermostat calls for cool.

Comment: I've uploaded an [image to chat](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K1PCD.png), that highlights the circuit using an external transformer when in cooling mode.